# How to get 2 column from the while. (in rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

what i do wrong?
 
i need to map items in two columns for example.
If i have 4 items , draw 1 column with class "col-md-3"
if i have 8 items, draw 2 column with class "col-md-3"
if i have 12 items, draw 3 column with class "col-md-3"

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:lowcat_ids, @lowcat, :id, :translated_name) do |b| %>

            <% $i = 1 %>
            <% while $i < 11 do %>

                <% if ($i < 5) %>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="checkbox flat-checkbox">
                            <%= b.label do %>
                                <%= b.check_box %>
                                <span class="fa fa-check"></span>
                                <%= b.text %>
                            <% end %> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <% end %>

                <% if ($i > 4)  %>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="checkbox flat-checkbox">
                            <%= b.label do %>
                                <%= b.check_box %>
                                <span class="fa fa-check"></span>
                                <%= b.text %>
                            <% end %> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <% end %>

                <% $i +=1 %>

            <% end %>

        <% end %>
```

Comment: why do you need a global variable there?

Comment: Why do you expect `collection_check_boxes` to expect the block? Also, the main problem with this code is it’s `php` written with the non-idiomatic worst ruby syntax. `while` loops are out of common use in `ruby`.

Comment: @mudasobwa, how i can resolve this problem in rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple calculation on i would give you the number of columns you would need

```
(i.to_f / 4).ceil
```

given that i is the count of the items you have